# Should I use laravel collective or another component?

Tags: forms, laravel, components

I'm starting with Laravel and I've some doubts about the external components.

I've already used the [laravel collective](https://laravelcollective.com/) and the [adamwathan/bootforms](https://github.com/adamwathan/bootforms) and the both show me advantage and disadvantage. I've searched for information or discussion about this and a I didn't find anything

For example, I can build forms extremely fast with these components, but I got limited sometimes.

According with the about session of the laravel Collective they say:

> The Laravel Collective is a community organization designed to maintain components that have been removed from the Laravel Framework core

So, if the form is removed from the core, should I continue using this component?

And in the readme from the Bootform, they say

> Probably not perfect for your super custom branded ready-for-release apps, but a huge time saver when you are still in the prototyping stage!

What do you think about using external components? Do you think it's a good ideia to use or do you prefer the original core from the Laravel?

Comment: I'm not sure about bootforms, but laravel collective is actively maintained. I had issues upgrading to Laravel 5.3 and on their twitter feed they indicated which version to use, which worked 100%. After updating everything it still worked with no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 3 weeks working with Laravel. I've learned somethings:

If you want to build easy forms without html, I recommend you to use the [AdamWathan bootform](https://github.com/adamwathan/bootforms) or [Laravel collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html). The only problem is: These tools doesn't has a good option with you want a very customizable field.

**Bootform**

Pros

1. Bootform has more components and functions
2. Reduced Boilerplate
3. Automatic Validation State
4. Some custom forms, like the horizontal forms

Cons

1. Some difficulties with documentation

**Laravel Collective**

Pros

1. All necessary things to build a laravel form, like the CSRF Protection and hidden fields.

**What I do**

Actually, I'm working with Collective and html. I use a mix of the both, when I need a simple field or specific fields (csrf protection, for example) I use collective and if I need a more customizable field, like a button with an icon or a special element in bootstrap, I use just HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've had the same dilemma, so I decided to examine Laravel Collective Html package.

I wanted to share my thoughts, therefore I created the following post: [Is it beneficial to add Laravel Collective Html into your Laravel Project](http://blog.tekmi.nl/is-it-beneficial-to-add-laravel-collective-html-package-into-your-laravel-project/)

Hope you will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to personal preference, Laravel Collectives gives you ease of pre selecting select inputs, csrf out of the box, etc... I found myself using it less and less and then eventually just stopped pulling it in altogether.